# jQuery-UI scrolls up DIV before hiding it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a DIV which is scrollable. If I try to hide it with `toggle()` using an effect from jQuery-UI, then for some reason it scrolls the DIV to top just before the hiding animation starts..

If I only use the `toggle()` function without an effect like this

```
$('#myDiv').toggle();
```

then it works OK - the DIV remains in it's scrolled position and then hides, however I need to use

```
$('#myDiv').toggle('drop');
```

and preserve the scroll state. It looks like something is resetting the `scrollTop` implicitly but I can't figure out how to prevent it.

Can someone shed some light on this, please?

> jQuery 1.11.2
>
> jQuery-UI v1.11.2
>
> Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure it out. The problem was in jQuery-UI, it was probably a **bug in the 1.11.2 version**. I have **upgraded to 1.12.0 version** and the problem went away - DIV is being toggled in it's scrolled state.